# What is Earth Movers Distance and how is it used in pattern recognition?

Tags: computer-vision

I have obtained [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance#Applications) from Wikipedia about the application of Earth Movers Distance to pattern recognition. Can anybody explain the concept of `signature` used in this Wikipedia article. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A set of clusters. Each cluster is represented by a pair with (1) one single point (usually the center in the cluster) ,and (2) a weight coefficient that usually in proportional to the size of the corresponding cluster. Note that the point can be anything including the coordinates of the pixel, the color information, intensity...etc.